# multiplication of xmm register

Tags: assembly, x86, simd

I'm having problem with multiplication of two register in assembly sse.
Here there is my code:

```
moltiplicazionePuntoPunto:
    mov edx,[esp+20]                 ; edx = fxx
    mov esi,[esp+4]                  ; esi = fx
    mov edi,[esp+8]                  ; edi = fy
    xor eax,eax                      ; i=0
 fori:   cmp eax,[esp+12]            ; confronta i con N
    jge endfori
    xor ebx,ebx                       ; j=0
 forj:   cmp ebx,[esp+16]             ; confronta j con M
    jge endforj   
    mov ecx,eax
    imul ecx,[esp+16]                 ; ecx = i*M
    add ecx,ebx                       ; ecx = i*M+j
    movss xmm5,[esi+ecx*4]            ; xmm5 = fx[i*M+j]
    movss xmm6,[edi+ecx*4]            ; xmm6 = fy[i*M+j]
    mulps xmm5,xmm6                   ; xmm7 = fx[i*M+j]*fx[i*M+j]
    movss [edx+ecx*4],xmm5            ; fxx[i*M+j] = fx*fx
    inc ebx
    jmp forj
 endforj:
    inc eax
    jmp fori
 endfori:
```

This code modify the matrix fxx where the element fxx[i*M+j] = fx[i*M+j] * fy[i*M+j]. The problem is when i do the operation `mulps xmm5,xmm6` the result is 0.

Comment: if `mulps xmm5,xmm6` is zero, then one of `xmm5` or `xmm6` was zero. So which one it is? And why don't you use for example C++, it would certainly produce faster loop, at least it would optimize the `i*M`, etc... plus it would be probably easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Actually there are of course other corner cases, where float x * float y = 0, even when x/y are both non-zero, as float itself has limited precision, so for example `1e-23 * 1e-23 = 0`, etc... Without some example data from debugger it is impossible to tell what did you encounter, and if you see the data, you probably see also the answer.

Comment: i think that the problem is the mulps istruction not the value of the registers. Because if i change the istruction mulps with the istruction addps the code works

Comment: Like your CPU is broken and the `mulps` is not doing what it should, right? Use common sense, 90% of the SW would fail on such machine. Problem is in your code and/or data, not the instruction, instruction works correctly. You didn't provide any particular test case ([MCVE] including input data, expected output data, and real output data). I tried my C++ below from answer over cpp.sh online site, and it works as expected, I will update the answer with fully working example.

Comment: problem solved. The problem was that i passed from C a matrix of int. Instead, if i pass a matrix of float the code works. Thank you to everyone. Sorry but i'm new to assembly

Comment: Use `mulss xmm5,[edi+ecx*4]`.  You don't need 4-wide packed multiply on the zeros in the upper lanes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved. The problem was that i passed from C a matrix of int. Instead, if i pass a matrix of float the code works.

Answer (score 0):

For example the simplified C++, it will just go through all elements of matrix, because that is what your `[i,j]` nested looping does. You don't need to calculate `i*M+j`, as your formula does not use i/j in any particular way, it just goes through all elements once:

```
void muldata(float* fxx, const float* fx, const float* fy, const unsigned int M, const unsigned int N) {
    int ofs = 0;
    do {
        fxx[ofs] = fx[ofs] * fy[ofs];
        ++ofs;
    } while (ofs < M*N);
}
```

Will make `clang -O3 -m32` (v4.0.0) produce this:

```
muldata(float*, float const*, float const*, unsigned int, unsigned int):                   # @muldata(float*, float const*, float const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)
        push    ebp
        push    ebx
        push    edi
        push    esi
        sub     esp, 12
        mov     esi, dword ptr [esp + 48]
        mov     edi, dword ptr [esp + 40]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [esp + 36]
        mov     edx, dword ptr [esp + 32]
        mov     eax, 1
        imul    esi, dword ptr [esp + 44]
        cmp     esi, 1
        cmova   eax, esi
        xor     ebp, ebp
        cmp     eax, 8
        jb      .LBB0_7
        mov     ebx, eax
        and     ebx, -8
        je      .LBB0_7
        mov     dword ptr [esp + 4], eax # 4-byte Spill
        cmp     esi, 1
        mov     eax, 1
        mov     dword ptr [esp], ebx    # 4-byte Spill
        cmova   eax, esi
        lea     ebx, [ecx + 4*eax]
        lea     edi, [edx + 4*eax]
        mov     dword ptr [esp + 8], ebx # 4-byte Spill
        mov     ebx, dword ptr [esp + 40]
        cmp     edx, dword ptr [esp + 8] # 4-byte Folded Reload
        lea     eax, [ebx + 4*eax]
        sbb     bl, bl
        cmp     ecx, edi
        sbb     bh, bh
        and     bh, bl
        cmp     edx, eax
        sbb     al, al
        cmp     dword ptr [esp + 40], edi
        mov     edi, dword ptr [esp + 40]
        sbb     ah, ah
        test    bh, 1
        jne     .LBB0_7
        and     al, ah
        and     al, 1
        jne     .LBB0_7
        mov     eax, dword ptr [esp]    # 4-byte Reload
        lea     ebx, [edi + 16]
        lea     ebp, [ecx + 16]
        lea     edi, [edx + 16]
.LBB0_5:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [ebp - 16]
        movups  xmm2, xmmword ptr [ebx - 16]
        movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [ebp]
        movups  xmm3, xmmword ptr [ebx]
        add     ebp, 32
        add     ebx, 32
        mulps   xmm2, xmm0
        mulps   xmm3, xmm1
        movups  xmmword ptr [edi - 16], xmm2
        movups  xmmword ptr [edi], xmm3
        add     edi, 32
        add     eax, -8
        jne     .LBB0_5
        mov     eax, dword ptr [esp]    # 4-byte Reload
        mov     edi, dword ptr [esp + 40]
        cmp     dword ptr [esp + 4], eax # 4-byte Folded Reload
        mov     ebp, eax
        je      .LBB0_8
.LBB0_7:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [ecx + 4*ebp] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
        mulss   xmm0, dword ptr [edi + 4*ebp]
        movss   dword ptr [edx + 4*ebp], xmm0
        inc     ebp
        cmp     ebp, esi
        jb      .LBB0_7
.LBB0_8:
        add     esp, 12
        pop     esi
        pop     edi
        pop     ebx
        pop     ebp
        ret
```

Which is by far superior to your code (includes vectorization of loop by default).

And it would produce probably even something better, if you would specify alignment of the pointers and make M/N compile time constant.

---

I just verified the C++ variant works by going to cpp.sh site and extending it to this:

```
#include <iostream>

void muldata(float* fxx, const float* fx, const float* fy, const unsigned int M, const unsigned int N) {
    unsigned int ofs = 0;
    do {
        fxx[ofs] = fx[ofs] * fy[ofs];
        ++ofs;
    } while (ofs < M*N);
}

int main()
{
    // constexpr unsigned int M = 1;
    // constexpr unsigned int N = 1;
    // const float fx[M*N] = { 2.2f };
    // const float fy[M*N] = { 3.3f };

    constexpr unsigned int M = 3;
    constexpr unsigned int N = 2;
    const float fx[M*N] = { 2.2f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f, 1e-24f };
    const float fy[M*N] = { 3.3f, 3.3f, 3.3f,
                            5.5f, 1e30f, 1e-24f };

    float fr[M*N];
    muldata(fr, fx, fy, M, N);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < M; ++j) std::cout << fr[i*M+j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
7.26 3.3 0 
5.5 1e+30 0
```

There's also commented out 1x1 input data, which should be the first thing to debug in your case. Try to make this example work in your favourite C++ IDE, then replace the `muldata` with your assembly code, and debug through it, to see where it goes off.